# How is a process defined as running in background?

Tags: windows, process

How is a process defined as running in background?
Would it be if it has no visible windows. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How is a process defined as running in background?

> A background process is a computer process that runs behind the scenes
>   (i.e., in the background) and without user intervention. Typical tasks
>   for these processes include logging, system monitoring, scheduling,
>   and user notification. The background process usually is a child
>   process created by a control process for processing computing task.
>   After the creation, the child process will run on its own course for
>   performing the task independent of the control process, therefore, the
>   control process is free of performing other designated task.
>
> On a Windows system, this term may be used to either refer to a
>   computer program that does not create a user interface, or a Windows
>   service. The former are started just as any other program is started,
>   e.g., via Start menu. Windows services, on the other hand, are started
>   by Service Control Manager. In Windows Vista and later, they are run
>   in a separate session. There is no limit on how much a system service
>   or background process can use system resources. Indeed, in the Windows
>   Server family of Microsoft operating systems, background processes are
>   expected to be the principal consumers of system resources.

[Background process - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_process)

> Would it be if it has no visible windows.

Not necessarily. A background process may open a window when it has some information it needs to communicate to the user, for example an error message or something else that requires the user's attention.

Comment: Too complicated. I believe that in Windows interactive programs are foreground and non-interactive ones are background, basically defined by whether the program is waiting for user input of any kind (graphic or keyboard).

Comment: @harrymc So what about services that are also waiting for user input, for example plugging in a USB drive is effectively user input as is plugging in some headphones. In any case, I value Wikipedia (which is backed up by many references) over your beliefs. You have not provided any citations to support your belief.

Comment: Wikipedia is correct, just too wordy. Plugging USB: User input is not the same as user action. My belief is based on many texts I have seen over the years, but no point in searching them out,